# Save multiple pieces of data using Xml without stored procedure (.net/sqlcommand)

Tags: .net

I want to save multiple pieces of data in my application, I can save multiple bits ofdata using XML with my stored procedure, but my client doesn't want to  use stored procedures. So is there any way to save multiple records in database?

Thanks

Comment: I  am  using  SqlBulkCopy...  its  working  for  me

Answer (score 1):

I  am  using **SqlBulkCopy**  and  Its  working for me